# Python date format Convert to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have df as below, however the format is object. I am trying to convert to date format in python.

| Shift End |
| --- |
| 2/9/2001 6:30:00 PM |
| 2/10/2001 6:30:00 PM |
| 2/11/2001 6:30:00 PM |
| 2/12/2001 6:30:00 PM |
| 2/13/2001 6:30:00 PM |
| 2/8/2001 12:30:00 PM |

I ma trying to use use below, but I get error time data '2/9/2001 10:00:00 AM' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p'

```
df["Shift Start "].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p'))
```

Comment: why the microseconds `.%f`?

Comment: `df["Shift Start "] = pd.to_datetime(df["Shift Start "])` should do the trick; I think you only need the specific parsing directive (`'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'`) if you want the method to raise an error in case the format changes within the column.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with change format for matching your data - change `%Y` for YYYY , remove microseconds `%f` and change `.` to `:`:

```
df["Shift Start "] = pd.to_datetime(df["Shift Start "], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```